# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\TransactionsController::store(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Tags: php, laravel

I have got an error that says:

> Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\TransactionsController::store(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected in the TransactionsController::store when i try to create Transactions and update the User's account in the TransactionsController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Http\Requests\TransactionsRequest;
use App\Traits\MakeTransactions;
use App\User;
use App\Transaction;
use DB;

class TransactionsController extends Controller
{
    use MakeTransactions;

    public function create()
    {
        $accno = auth()->user()->accno;

        $account = DB::table('users')
            ->join('accounts', 'users.accno', '=', 'accounts.accno')
            ->select('users.*', 'accounts.*')
            ->get();

        return view('dashboard.user.make_a_transfer.create', compact('account'));
    }

    public function store(TransactionsRequest $requestFields,$id)
    {   
        $transactions = $this->Transfer($requestFields);

        $account = Account::find($id);

        $bal = $account->amt_paid + $transctions->amt;
        $account->total = $bal;
        $account->save(); 

        return redirect('/make_transfer')->with('success', 'Transaction has been made');
    }

    public function saveTransaction($data)
    {   
        
        return true;

    }
}
```

my routes web,php

```
Route::get('/make_transfer', 'TransactionsController@create')->name('make_transfer');
Route::post('/create/make_transfer',['as'=>'transactions.store','uses'=>'TransactionsController@store']);
    Route::get('/account_details', 'TransferController@details')->name('account_details');
```

I'm using a create.blade.php file;

```
@extends('../../../layouts/dashboard')
@section('content')
<div class="page-wrapper">
            <div class="page-breadcrumb">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 d-flex no-block align-items-center">
                        <h4 class="page-title"></h4>
                        <div class="ml-auto text-right">
                            <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Make Transfer</li>
                                </ol>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body wizard-content">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Make Bank Transfers</h4>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle"></h6>

                        @if ($errors->any())
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <br /> 
                        @endif
                        <form id="example-form" action="/create/make_transfer/{id}" method="POST" class="m-t-40">
                            <div>
                            @csrf
                            <div class="form-group">    
                                <label for="reciever_name">Reciever Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="reciever_name" value="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">    
                                <label for="reciever_bank">Reciever Bank:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="reciever_bank" value="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">    
                                <label for="reciever_accno">Reciever Account Number:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="reciever_accno" value="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">    
                                <label for="routing_no">Routing Number:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="routing_no" value="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">    
                                <label for="amt">Amount:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amt" value="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">    
                                <label for="fund_option">Fund Options:</label>
                                <select name="fund_option">
                                    <option value="">Select Option</option>
                                    <option value="Domestic">Domestic Transfer</option>
                                    <option value="Local">Local Transfer</option>
                                    <option value="Offshore">International Transfer</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">    
                                <label for="description">Description:</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="description" value=""></textarea>
                            </div>
                                <button type="submit">Make Transfer</button>
                                <section>
                                    <input id="acceptTerms" name="acceptTerms" type="checkbox" class="required">
                                    <label for="acceptTerms">I agree with the Terms and Conditions.</label>
                                </section>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I need help updating the Account Table using the **$id** after the user makes a Transfer request.

Comment: plz post your route.

Comment: when you ask questions please give the full code. It will help to answer. Thanks

Comment: can you  give```dump()``` the value of ```$account``` and ```$transactions```?

Comment: please explain to me how i could use ```dump()``` i try using dump($account ) dump($transactions); like this ```public function store(TransactionsRequest $requestFields,$id)
    {   
        $transactions = $this->Transfer($requestFields);

        $account = Account::find($id);

        $bal = $account->amt_paid + $transctions->amt;
        $account->total = $bal;
        $account->save(); 

        dump($account);
        dump($transactions);
        // return redirect('/make_transfer')->with('success', 'Transaction has been made');
    }```

Comment: just use  like ```dump($account);```  and ```dump($transactions);``` . and comment the value.

Comment: yes exactly and give the value.

Answer (score 2):

`public function store(TransactionsRequest $requestFields,$id)`

So your Function expects two arguments one is `$requestFields` which is your function getting no doubt but where is `$id`. You are not passing $id to the function,

why am I saying that because when I checked your route, you are not passing any parameter named as id.

`Route::post('/create/make_transfer',['as'=>'transactions.store','uses'=>'TransactionsController@store']);`

So I suggest you check did you build your program for expect parameter or you just using it from the form request.

Perhaps your route should be like below

`Route::post('/create/make_transfer/{id}',['as'=>'transactions.store','uses'=>'TransactionsController@store']);`

Now when you calling this route , you have to call it like below

`route('transactions.store',['id'=>$yourID])`

Comment: please how can I call the route ```route('transactions.store',['id'=>$yourID])```, I'm trying to  find this user accno using ```$account = Account::find($id);```

Comment: where you getting this $id

Comment: I have updated the question by showing my create.blade.php file where $id is passed from

Comment: /create/make_transfer/{id}   the id is current logged in user id?

Comment: then just remove $if from function and use it like Auth::id();  not forget to use `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` on the top of your controller